# How import geoserver mbtiles pbf?

Tags: geoserver

I try to import `mbtiles` from `openmaptiles.org` in geoserver.
When I try to add a layer, I get the message:

```
"No enum constant org.geotools.mbtiles.MBTilesMetadata.t_format.PBF"
```

How can i resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer does not support serving of vector tiles stored in MBTiles now.

Use the free TileServer GL open-source project instead - as the map server software for serving the vector tiles available from OpenMapTiles.org.

TileServer GL will also provide you with raster tiles (PNG/JPEG tiles for use in Leaflet or other traditional viewers and old browsers) created on demand from vector tiles on your server - and it will deliver WMTS service, for openning the map layers in QGIS, ArcGIS, etc.

See: https://openmaptiles.org/docs/host/tileserver-gl/ and https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl

Manual of TileServer GL is available at http://tileserver.readthedocs.io/

Disclaimer: we are authors of the OpenMapTiles.org project which you mention in your question, and you have probably downloaded the MBTiles file from our server.
We are also programmers behind the TileServer GL project. As such we are affiliated with the above-mentioned projects. The GeoServer developers may provide you with more details about a planned (or not?) support of vector tiles served from MBTiles format.